# How do I find out the higher variable

Tags: python

I need to find the higher variable but it says:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
could anyone help me find the higher number of total1 and total2.
thank you

```
price1 = int(input('Cost of first product($): '))
price2 = int(input('Cost of second product($): '))
mass1 = int(input('Mass of first product(g): '))
mass2 = int(input('Mass of second product(g): '))
total1 = print('The unit price of Product One is', price1/mass1, '$/g.')
total2 = print('The unit price of Product One is', price2/mass2, '$/g.')
if total1 > total2:
  print ('Product 1 is of better value.)
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. first: `total1 = price1/mass1`, then print and compare...

Comment: Welcome to SO.   I think what you mean to do is ```total1 = price1/mass1``` and then ```print("The unit price of Product One is ', total1, '$/g.')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
price1 = int(input('Cost of first product($): '))
price2 = int(input('Cost of second product($): '))
mass1 = int(input('Mass of first product(g): '))
mass2 = int(input('Mass of second product(g): '))
print('Unit proce of product onr ',price1/mass1,'$/g.')
print('Unit proce of product onr ',price2/mass2 ,'$/g.')
total1 = price1/mass1
total2 = price2/mass2
if total1 > total2:
    print ('Product 1 is of better value.')
elif total2>total1:
    print ('Product 2 is of better value.')
else:
    print ('Product 1 and 2 are equal.')
```

'print' return None , that why you are getting TypeError